# WS JUnit Testing: Cannot find dispatch method for {}

Tags: java, web-services, soap, junit

**I have to develop several WS in Java. Cause I have no previous experience with this, I started with a simple example. Here the WS:**

```
@WebService
public interface DataExchangeWebService {

    public int doubleIt(int numberToDouble);

}

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange",
            portName = "DataExchangePort",
            serviceName = "DataExchangeService",
            endpointInterface = "xyz.DataExchangeWebService")
public class DataExchangeWebServiceImpl implements DataExchangeWebService {

    @Override
    public int doubleIt(int numberToDouble) {
        return numberToDouble * 2;
    }

}
```

**Now I would like to test this Service only via JUnit. I found [this](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/junit_web_service_testing) blog entry, which builds the starting point for my test case. To keep it simple, I used the Java Endpoint class.**

```
protected static URL wsdlURL;

protected static QName serviceName;

protected static QName portName;

protected static Endpoint endpoint;

protected static String address;

static {
    serviceName = new QName("http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange", "DataExchangeService");
    portName = new QName("http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange", "DataExchangePort");
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    address = "http://localhost:9000/ws/DataExchange";
    wsdlURL = new URL(address + "?wsdl");
    endpoint = Endpoint.publish(address, new DataExchangeWebServiceImpl());
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    endpoint.stop();
}
```

**This publishes the WS and generates the following WSDL:**

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is 
    JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is 
    JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange"
    name="DataExchangeService">
    <import namespace="http://dataexchange.sys.cs.iface.service.appserver.xyz/"
        location="http://localhost:9000/ws/DataExchange?wsdl=1" />
    <binding xmlns:ns1="http://dataexchange.sys.cs.iface.service.appserver.xyz/"
        name="DataExchangePortBinding" type="ns1:DataExchangeWebService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
            style="document" />
        <operation name="doubleIt">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="DataExchangeService">
        <port name="DataExchangePort" binding="tns:DataExchangePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9000/ws/DataExchange" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**Now I have two test cases. The first one, uses the plain service to make the request:**

```
public void raw_service() {
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);
    DataExchangeWebService dataExchangeWebService = service.getPort(portName, DataExchangeWebService.class);
    int resp = dataExchangeWebService.doubleIt(10);
    assertEquals(20, resp);
}
```

**This one is working fine. The problematic is the second one. It uses a a SOAP message to make the request:**

```
 public void raw_service_with_full_soap_message() throws DOMException, SOAPException, IOException {
        Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);
        Dispatch<SOAPMessage> disp = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fullSOAPMessage.xml");
        SOAPMessage reqMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
        assertNotNull(reqMsg);
        SOAPMessage response = disp.invoke(reqMsg);
        assertEquals("Double-It not doubling zero correctly", "0", response.getSOAPBody().getTextContent().trim());
    }
```

**The fullSOAPMessage.xml looks as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:doubleIt xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange">
         <numberToDouble>0</numberToDouble>
      </ns2:doubleIt>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**JUnit fails with:**

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {http://www.example.com/ws/DataExchange}doubleIt
```

**The research I have done so far only revealed, that this has something to do with conflicts between the target namespace of the WS and the SOAP message. But in my eyes thats not the case here.
Some ideas about how to solve this or whats going on?**